# Count the number of times values appear next to eachother

Tags: python, list, counting

I have a list that looks like:

```
['C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C']
```

and I want to be able to count the number of times one, two, or three H's appear next to each-other but not anything above this.

So in the above example, HHH appears 0 times, HH appears two times, and H appears once.

I've tried to build a for loop that iterates over current and previous position but I feel this is too long winded.

Comment: What about three 'H'?

Comment: That's actually even more confusing :(. Wouldn't 4 Hs also equal to 2-2Hs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C']

counts = defaultdict(int)
for _, group in groupby(lst):
    s = ''.join(group)
    if len(s) < 4:
        counts[s] += 1

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'CC': 1, 'HH': 2, 'E': 1, 'H': 1, 'CCC': 1, 'C': 2}
```

The idea is to find the *run* of consecutive letters with groupby and store the count in a dictionary, in this case a defaultdict.

Comment: This is a great answer and very neat, thank you. Is there a way to find out the original position of where the H's are? Ie the lone H, what position was it originally in the sequence.. I tried to add a ```count = 0``` then ```counter = counter+1``` and printed this just after the ```if``` statement, is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You could the index too, but do you need the positions of all the lone `H`?

Comment: Yes, so for example, in this case, there is one lone H in position 6, is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this  maybe? It print all the number H appear next to each other.

```
X = ['C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C']
from collections import Counter
def cnt(X,c):
    i = 0
    count = Counter()
    temp = 0 #temporary variable to store counter
    while i < len(X):
        if X[i] != c:
            i += 1
        else:
            while i < len(X) and X[i] == c: #keep looping until end of array or different character
                temp += 1
                i += 1
            count[temp] += 1
            temp = 0
    print(count)
cnt(X,'H')

#Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 4: 1})
```